# Get open profit of a specific trade (and not all open trades)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How can I get the value of the open profit of a specific open trade, and note all the open trades?

My strategy config :

- pyramiding=2
- strategy.cash
- default_qty_type=strategy.cash
- close_entries_rule = default (FIFO I supposed)

```
if strategy.openprofit>45
    profit45:=true
if profit45 and strategy.openprofit<20
    strategy.close("Short", comment="Close Long")
    profit45 := false
```

If I have 2 open trades, it will be the sum of my 2 trades that will be considered.

Is it possible to get the open profit of an identified trade?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`strategy.opentrades.profit()` returns the profit/loss of the open trade.

```
strategy.opentrades.profit(trade_num) → series float
```

You can use the `trade_num` parameter to specify which open order to point to.

> ***trade_num (series int)*** The trade number of the open trade. The number
> of the first trade is zero.

```
plot(strategy.opentrades.profit(strategy.opentrades - 1), "Profit of the latest open trade")
```